# php proc_open file descriptor in bash command

Tags: php, bash, shell, proc-open

When we use `proc_open` in PHP:

```
<?php

$descriptors = array(
    array('pipe', 'r'),
    array('pipe', 'w'),
    array('pipe', 'w'),
);

$cmd = 'cat <(ls)';
//$cmd = 'ls';
echo $cmd . PHP_EOL;
$ph = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);
echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
proc_close($ph);
```

When run this script, an error occurred:

```
$ php test.php 
cat <(ls)
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

but run the raw cmd:

```
$ cat <(ls)
clusterRegions.php
composer.json
composer.lock
cvCells.php
kent
prepareForTF.php
README.txt
scoreRegions.php
test.php
tests
vendor
```

Seems that the `<()` thing cannot be recognized by `proc_open`.
So how to pass a bash command with a file descriptor to `proc_open` ?

Comment: `proc_open` and friends are almost certainly using `/bin/sh` by default. Which on many systems doesn't support process substitution. You can see if you can get `proc_open` to use `/bin/bash` via config or something or you can manually run `bash` in the `proc_open` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Etan Reisner, you are right, when I change to `bash`, it runs well.

```
$cmd = 'bash -c "cat <(ls)"';
```